# Replacing a variable in vba powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, variables, powerpoint

I am trying to replace and save an integer in VBA Powerpoint.

I have a variable in 1 Subroutine named projectId. At the moment, the variable is set to 617. In another subroutine I am running a user input method that prompts the user for a new projectId and stores the new projectId to replace the "617". The only issue is the projectId go to 0 when I close the PowerPoint and reopen it.

Is there any way to physically replace the code `projectId = 617` with `projectId = 699` for this example.

Below is the code Im working with, notice that **`projId`** is a global veriable:

```
    Dim projId As Integer
```

---

```
Sub ChangeProjID()
    Dim strProjId As String

    Dim intProjId As Integer

    strProjId = InputBox("Enter the Project ID given by example:", "Project ID Input")

    On Error GoTo NotValidID
    intProjId = CInt(strProjId)
    projId = intProjId
    MsgBox " Your new project ID will be set to " & intProjId & " until changed again"

    Exit Sub

NotValidID:

    MsgBox " You must enter a valid integer"

    End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub CommentConnect(control As IRibbonControl)


    Dim URL As String
    projId = 617
    URL = "example.com/prID="


    ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink (URL & projId)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMan's got the right idea ... store the value in non-volatile memory.

Luckily, PowerPoint has a feature that's perfect for this:  Tags.

```
With ActivePresentation
  .Tags.Add "ProjectID", Cstr(intProjID)
End With
```

The string version of intProjID is now a permanent "tag" attached to the presentation object.  To retrieve it:

```
MsgBox ActivePresentation.Tags("ProjectID")
```

Each presentation, slide and shape can have pretty much as many of these tags as you like.

Comment: Steve, How would I reference that tag from inside vba?

Comment: It worked!! Thanks so much guys! You all are life savers. I wish I could give you both a check!

Answer (score 2):

If `CommentConnect()` is called *after* `ChangeProjID()`, the line `projId = 617` will override any value the user entered in `ChangeProjID()`.

I see a couple of options for fixing this.

1. Change the signature of `ChangeProjID()` to:
   `Function ChangeProjID() as Integer`
   then change the line in `CommentConnect to:`
   `projId = ChangeProjID()`
2. Change the line in `CommentConnect()` to:
   `If projId = 0 then`
     `projId = 617 'use this value as a default`
   `End If`

For option 1, the complete, changed code would look like:

```
Function ChangeProjID() As Integer
    Dim strProjId As String
    Dim intProjId As Integer

    strProjId = InputBox("Enter the Project ID given by example:", "Project ID Input")

    On Error GoTo NotValidID
    intProjId = CInt(strProjId)
    MsgBox " Your new project ID will be set to " & intProjId & " until changed again"
    ChangeProjID = intProjId

    Exit Sub

NotValidID:
    MsgBox " You must enter a valid integer"
End Sub

Public Sub CommentConnect(control As IRibbonControl)
    Dim URL As String
    projId = ChangeProjID
    URL = "example.com/prID="
    ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink (URL & projId)
End Sub
```

The complete, changed code for option 2 would be:

```
Public Sub CommentConnect(control As IRibbonControl)


    Dim URL As String
    if projId = 0 then
      projId = 617           'use project 617 as the default
    End If
    URL = "example.com/prID="


    ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink (URL & projId)

End Sub
```

Note that whatever you do, `projId` will default to `0` when you first open the PPTX - that's the nature of variables, they have a default value when the application starts until set otherwise.

If you want, you can create some sort of mechanism for storing the `projId` in non-volatile memory (a text file, the registry, a hidden (background color = foreground color) field on the first slide of the PPT, etc). Or you can have some sort of initialization for `projId` so that it always gets set to some known, non-zero value when your code is launched, but it will *not* retain its last set value all by itself.

Comment: Thanks FreeMan. Hows this sound... If I create a textbox on the first page that contains the projId entered by the userInput, could I save id that way and reference it from within the subroutine?

Comment: Absolutely! that's what `a hidden (background color = foreground color) field on the first slide of the PPT` was referring to. [Steve](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30759891/2344413)'s suggestion about using a `.tag` will work quite well, also.